# Message tone played multiple times on receiving message/notification on iOS 5

Tags: ios, audio

I've an iPhone 4 and I've installed iOS 5 on it. Since then, whenever I receive a text message or an app notification, the tone plays like "tre..tre..tre..tre..te..tre..tre...tring". Sometimes it takes a whole 5 to 7 secs for the sound to be complete.

At first, I thought it's because of the beta; but I guess they should've fixed it by now as it is already some Beta 3 if I'm not wrong!

Does anyone know any settings change/fixes that can fix it?

Comment: Have you tried changing the text tone to something else to see if it's a problem with all of them?

Comment: I Changed the tone to some other one. When I receive a text message, it works fine but when I receive a push notification from an app, life facebook push notifications, the same issue stays.

Comment: Is it the exact same ringtone for notifications, I've not properly been through all of them but it sounds like a new default one in the system.

Comment: I changed the sound to chime but when I receive a app push notification, the old tri-tone is played. When I receive a text-message, the Chime tone is played though.

Comment: Yup, happening to my 3GS too. Sounds like the tri-tone has a stammer, starting and stopping. I haven't found a fix other than to keep on silent mode.

Comment: My sms alert tone (IOS 5) also seems to have issue. The tone repeat itself (as if like a broken record or stammering) multiple times when i receive any sms.

Comment: There used to be an option on 4.3 how often you want an alert sound to play. That option is gone in iOS 5. Bug?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I had the exact same issue after updating to IOS 5, SMS tones sounded like a stuck record and very garbled. Solution is back-up your iphone then do a complete restore and at the end set up as a new iphone NOT backup from previous. The back-up can cause glitches when 1st updating from 4.3.5 to 5. Then unplug and plug back in and right click your iphone and do a "restore from back-up" after the setup as new iphone. Hope that helps for you as it did for me.

Comment: The most important part of this process is setting up as a NEW iphone at the end of the restore.

Comment: `settings > general > reset > reset all settings` fixed it for me.